Mismatched in MODIS Data: Comparing GEE Downloads with Source HDF Files
I can export MODIS data using the geemap library in Python or from Google Earth Engine (both option results are the same). However, I am comparing the data downloaded via GEE with the data downloaded directly from the source and noticing inconsistencies in pixel values when inspecting the data in ArcGIS.
For Turkey, the tiles corresponding to H19, H20, H21, V4, and V5 result in 6 files for each year.
data-source: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod17a3hgfv061/

Below is the GEE code used to export the NPP data for Turkey in 2022:
// Load the NPP data for 2022 from MODIS
var npp2022 = ee.Image('MODIS/061/MYD17A3HGF/2022_01_01')
              .select('Npp')
              .multiply(0.0001)
              .rename('NPP_2022');

// Define the geometry for Turkey (can be obtained from the country boundaries)
var turkey = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Turkey'));

// Clip the NPP image to Turkey
var nppTurkey = npp2022.clip(turkey);

// Optionally, export the NPP image for Turkey
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: nppTurkey,
  description: 'NPP_2022_Turkey_Map',
  scale: 500,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  region: turkey,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

I have also found a very similar
question that recently asked.

Are all pixel vales different, or just some?

all pixel values are different. someone suggested that the issue might be related to the projection used during the export. I code the following settings but it did not worked. I will have double check.
{crs: "SR-ORG:6974", crsTransform: [463.3127165279165, 0, -20015109.354, 0, -463.3127165279167, 10007554.677003]}
